# jars are getting merged in classes.jar while using proguard android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

I am creating a library project (**AAR** file)

AAR file consists **libs** folder as it is and create **classes.jar** if proguard is not used.

But if I use **proguard** then **it merge all jars in classes.jar**.

I tried to **change build.gradle** from

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

to

```
provided fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Then it ***only compiles the libs*** and **include neither in libs folder nor in classes.jar**

This is my current proguard file

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!class/merging/*,!field/*,!class/unboxing/enum
#-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify

-dontshrink
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-verbose

# For enumeration classes
-keepclassmembers enum * {*;}

# For Libs
#-injars       libs\cc.jar
#-outjars      libs\cc_out.jar

-keepdirectories **libs**

# For parcelable and serializable object classes
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable {*;}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
   public static <fields>;
}

# preserve linenumber only
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes  SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature,Exceptions,InnerClasses,*Annotation*

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Please help to keep the jars in libs folder and avoid inclusion in classes.jar

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in 2016. See: https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar/issues/24